# Why I can't get TLV tag value for 57 by using EMV response?

Tags: android, emv, tlv

I tried to read visa card details.Using EMV response I can't get value for tag 57 to get PAN and Expire date.please can you help me because I am new to this.Thank you.

Comment: It's not a one step process. At what leve are you. Let know if what you have done so far ?

Answer (score 0):

Tag '57' is the Track 2 Equivalent Data, the PAN is individually stored in tag '5A'.

Anyway, in both cases, these tags can't be read using the GET DATA command, they are stored in records that can be retrieved using the READ RECORD command.

To know what records to read, you need to parse the Application File Locator (AFL, tag '94') received in the response to the GET PROCESSING OPTIONS command.

Let me know if you have other questions.

Hear is an example:

## Select Visa application

```
=> 00 A4 04 00 08 A0 00 00 00 03 10 10 03 00
<= 6F 1F 
         84 08 A000000003101003
         A5 13
               50 0E 5649534120435245444954203033
               87 01 03
   9000
```

## GPO

```
=> 80 A8 00 00 02 83 00 00
<= 77 17
         82 02 1000
         94 0C 08020200 SFI=1, record 2, no ODA
               18010101 SFI=3, record 1, ODA
               18020200 SFI=3, record 2, no ODA
         9FDC 02 3420
   9000
```

## Read record 2 of SFI 1

```
=> 00 B2 02 0C 00
<= 70 ...
   9000
```

## Read record 1 of SFI 3

```
=> 00 B2 01 1C 00
<= 70 ...
   9000
```

## Read record 2 of SFI 3

```
=> 00 B2 02 1C 00
<= 70 ...
   9000
```